# How to import and stitch together Typescript files in Java

Tags: java, json, typescript

I have a bunch of files in this way:

```
folder1:
   file1.ts
   file2.ts
folder2:
   file1.ts
   file2.ts
```

In these files I create and export some JSON like how its usually exported from Typescript.

In my main Index.ts file I have something like:

```
import folder1 from "folder1";
import folder2 from "folder2";

info = {
   paths: {
      ...folder1,
      ...folder2
     }
}
```

These files are stitched together in Typescript using the **'...' EMMET ABBREVIATION** . However I need to be importing these files using Java instead of Typescript and should also be stitching these files together in Java itself to make a single JSON file. I have no idea how to do this

Thank you so much for the help in advance :)

Comment: Can you please make your question more precise? If you want to process JSON in Java, you can use Google's Gson (see https://github.com/google/gson/)

Comment: Hi @sb27 the JSON is being created by the files I mentioned (file1.ts & file2.ts) using their export functionality. This is being called by index.ts which has ...folder1, ...folder2 which will basically call these files during runtime and stitch the files together into one JSON object. However, I want to be able to do all of this (importing and stitching these JSON) using these Typescript files in Java. Hope that's clearer :)

Comment: why you just make the file .json and import it to ts and then use eg. Google Gson in java

Comment: So you have many json objects and want them to be just concatenated? Like `{"a": 11, "b": 3}` + `{"e":"f","f":"erdf"}` -> `{"a": 11, "b": 3, "e":"f","f":"erdf"}`

Comment: @robert I want to keep my code on the server side and not on the client side. And my code on the server side runs Java.

Comment: @sb27 I can't do that as I have Typescript files that generate the JSON and not JSON files themselves.